# Smallest neighborhood containing two particular elements of a topological space

Tags: general-topology

Consider a Topological space $X.$ I have two fixed elements $a$ and $b.$ Now my question is can I find the smallest such open set that contains both $a$ and $b?$

The topological space does not necessarily posses any special property like Hausdorff or Metrizability.

I know that this is not possible for a single point. For example in $\mathbb R$ equipped with usual topology if I try to find the smallest neighborhood of $0$ we can't find one because for every nbd $\left({1\over n},{1\over m} \right)$ of $0$ there is an even smaller $\left({1\over p},{1\over q} \right)\subset \left({1\over n},{1\over m} \right)$. But can there be a smallest neighborhood of $0$ that also contains $1?$  Apparently **no** here too for similar reasons; we can consider the nbds $\left(0-{1\over n},1+{1\over n}\right).$

So is there any particular topology that enables the existence of such a **smallest neighborhood**? Is this possible at all in any space?

Comment: What do you means by ''smallest''? Does this means that the topology is induced by a metric ( so that the space is metrizable)?

Comment: It seems to me that you can't, but I don't have a specific counterexample. I assume by "smallest" you mean the intersection of all open sets containing $a$ and $b$. In general, there will be infinitely many such sets. And, in general, the intersection of infinitely many open sets needn't be open.

Comment: @EmilioNovati : no. **minimal**  comes closest to what I mean- a ndb which does not properly contain another containing both $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

The discrete and indiscrete topologies permit this.  In the first case it is $\{a,b\}$, in the second it is the whole space.

Comment: thank you very much. Any other non-trivial ones?

Comment: Any time $\{a,b\}$ is open, so you can have $\Bbb R \cup \{a,b\}$ as a space with the usual open sets of $\Bbb R$ plus $\{a,b\}$ (and, if you want, $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$) as a basis.  What you need to avoid is having $\{a,b\}$ not open but having steadily decreasing open sets around it.